# avoid OVER_QUERY_LIMIT in reverse geocoding

Tags: google-maps, reverse-geocoding

How to avoid OVER_QUERY_LIMIT in reverse Geo coding.
My code is given below.

```
<?php


        function getaddress($lat,$lng)
        {  
            $url = 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng='.trim($lat).','.trim($lng).'&sensor=false';
            $json = @file_get_contents($url);
            $data=json_decode($json); //pr($data);
            //echo $data['results']['0'];
            @$status = $data->status;

            if($status=="OK")
            return $data->results[0]->formatted_address;

            else
            return false;

        }
?>
```

How to avoid OVER_QUERY_LIMIT in reverse Geo coding.i have used sleep function but its not working.please help

Answer (score 0):

The OVER_QUERY_LIMIT refers to quota for the day or QPS.

You can also try to use usleep, time_nanosleep and time_sleep_until.

I haven't tried this, but you can also try to use register tick function http://php.net/manual/en/function.register-tick-function.php